# how to Show ID of table using c# entity code first

Tags: c#, entity

i'm working with c# windows App entity frame work code first,
and i need to get the last Id value of a table but +1 ( i need to add 1 to the Id value) to indelicate the next ID of the next insertion.

Comment: hi you can set in EF this id to be auto generated and when you insert new record your new object will get new ID passed to id in Db as well as you can get it in code as well .

Comment: check my answer I posted sample EF code first entity class for your refrence  you can use it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you are using Entity Framework, so I assume you have a context class that derives from `DbContext` which itself has a `DbSet` for the table in question.

So if you have something like this in your context class:

```
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

you can then use LINQ to Entities to do:

```
var nextId = context.Customers.Max(x => x.Id) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can set in EF id to be auto generated and when you insert new record your object will get new ID generated  in Db as well as you can get it in code as well .

```
public class Foo
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   -- here is how you can get id back 

var context = new TestContext();
        var newFoo = new Foo{ Name = "D" };
        context.Foos.Add(newFoo);
        context.SaveChanges();
        Console.Write(newFoo.Id);
       TextBox1.Text = newFoo.Id.ToString()
```

Comment: Noooo it's helpfull 2

Comment: Its good practice to have autoId so that you dont have to worry about inserting them . Also One point where my solution work better is the following . consider 2 user who opened you application and at that time ID was 1 so in the textbox next id is shown as 2 . if one user submit the information then his records wil be saved to database with id 2 but problem will occur  when 2 try to insert this records it will throw error because id 2 is already present in the database . Then you need  some more logic to handle it . in my solution you dont have to set next Id when you save .